# Send the image generated by "canvas", without saving it to a file

Tags: node.js, canvas, discord, discord.js

Is it possible to send image as base64, buffer, or DataURL?
As I saw in the source code Discord.JS, it can attach only the URL, file, or pipe stream. But is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the methods described in Federico Grandi's answer,
don't work in version 11.1.0. (The function that processes the buffer gets undefined).

[image: screenshot]

After the upgrade to version 11.3.2, the problem was resolved.

Comment: If I have grammatical and lexical errors in the answer - please edit.

Comment: And (if you can) put the image link into the !\[screenshot\](URL)

Comment: Glad to hear that! Using the stable version usually avoids getting this type of errors. I suggested an edit for your answer, as you asked

Comment: @FedericoGrandi Oh... The picture is gone... Maybe it's better to use !\[screenshot\]\(https://s22.postimg.cc/ddt6tuklt/image.png\)?

Comment: Done. If you want you can edit your own answers by clicking the edit button below

Comment: @FedericoGrandi I don't have enough reputation points to include images =D

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really into this stuff, but I think you can send a buffer: in the docs for [`TextChannel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) it says that you can send a [`BufferResolvable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/BufferResolvable), either by sending an [`Attachment`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Attachment) with that file or by setting that as `.file` in the [`MessageOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions) you pass in the `send()` function.

Comment: Oh, I tried all of your ways..
But sending buffer as {file:buffer} and as {files:[buffer]} returns an error "The resource must be a string or Buffer.".
After I checked the code, I find that code [Discord.JS 11.1.x: /src/client/ClientDataResolver.js]: 
https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/11.1.0/src/client/ClientDataResolver.js#L207
So it's not possible to send image as buffer from this way.

Comment: In the new versions there is checking for pipe stream.
So I can write pseudo-pipe object like: https://jsfiddle.net/bgL7ouqv/1/

Comment: Just noticed the first line in that function ... Strange, but it doesn't work when sending a buffer and I see an error ...

Comment: While debugging that function, noticed that the "resource" argument is undefined
https://s22.postimg.cc/ddt6tuklt/image.png My code: https://s22.postimg.cc/gknqdifch/image.png

Comment: Oh, it's a bug of Discord.js 11.0.0